# Creating fat files: libtool vs lipo (Should I prefer lipo?)

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, libtool-xcode, lipo

I wonder what would be the difference when using:

```
lipo -create i386/libAwesome.a armv7/libAwesome.a -o fat/libAwesome.a
```

and

```
libtool -static i386/libAwesome.a armv7/libAwesome.a -o fat/libAwesome.a
```

I have the impression that `lipo` is more general, and it will simply *stick* two files from different architectures while `libtool` is specific for libraries, Is this true?

Under what cases I should prefer Lipo over Libtool?

Comment: Why this is non constructive? I am looking for an objective reason or case in where I should use lip over libtool.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. It has an objective, non-opinion answer that we can determine by reading the documentation and/or experimenting.

Comment: If you run `file` on the output of the two commands, you'll see that both are “Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures”, but the `lipo`-created file encapsulates two Mach-O object files while the `libtool`-created file encapsulates two “current ar archive random library” files. I don't think the `lipo`-created file will work as a static library file. Furthermore, if you try to put more armv7 and i386 object files into the library, the `lipo` command will fail (because it can't put multiple object files with the same architecture into its output), while the `libtool` command will succeed.